# Token is not found in params in node

Tags: node.js, jwt

I was trying to verify the token and passes on url but it says  token not found

```
 const token = req.params.token;
 console.log(token);
 try {
     if (!token) {
         return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Token is missing' });
     }
     const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secrets);

 } catch (err) {
     console.error('JWT verification error:', err);
     res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid or expired token' });
 }
});
```